# Error on sending envelope through docusign api in apex class

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am getting below error when sending envelope through my apex class:

Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: This User lacks sufficient permissions. User does not have the permission to send envelopes

I am not able to figure out what the issue might be.

I have used the code in this GIT repo https://github.com/docusign/sfdc-recipe-embedded-signing/blob/master/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it sounds like you're not handling authentication well. The application is attempting to send as a user that doesn't have permission to send envelopes.